# How to automatically move contents of Recycle Bin to a directory in my hard drive?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, recycle-bin

Few months back, I paid a visit to my friend's house. I love deleting things from other people's hard drives. Shift & Delete are two of my favorite keys in the keyboard. To make some space, I shift-deleted a few old movies from his computer so that I could copy some new ones into the hard drive. Well....old movies were on the D drive.

As soon as I shift-deleted them from D, I simply checked the E drive. 20 GB of movies that I deleted from D drive were now on E. I was a bit confused. I checked the Recycle bin. Nothing was present.

Then I deleted (only delete, no Shift+Delete) some songs from D: they went to recycle bin. From recycle bin, I performed an *Empty Recycle Bin* option. Alas! it went back to E – the same place where the movies were moved to.

I asked him how he did it. He told me some network engineer (his brother's friend) did it on his recommendation and he didn't know how.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: It's a windows 8 desktop computer. Sorry. My mistake. @Tetsujin

Comment: I for one find the question confusing. What specifically is the "it" you want to do?  Delete the files and get the "normal" result, or replicate the bizarre behavior of this computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I must say that it's a stupid idea. Why would anyone deliberately do this to a computer?

And there's one crucial detail you didn't mention or probably forgot to check, that what would happen if you delete the data which the system just restored in E drive. What if it's in a loop and the procedure is not easily reversible?

Anyway it's an interesting topic. Kudos to the guy who got this idea and made it happen.

Well, now I'm not sure about this but I think it has something to do with VSS, **Volume Shadow Copy Service** in Windows operating systems. Your friend's computer would possibly be set to automatically create **System Restore Points** very often, probably more than once a day. And his "network engineer" guy must have used some forensic tool like **libvshadow** in this case, tweaked it a little bit to set it to recover the deleted data from the shadow copy to the E drive.

But it's highly unlikely. No one would go to such an extent to try this, and as Logan suggested it could be just some old software.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the Norton Protected Recycle Bin. Norton purchased the software from another company and rebranded it - it wouldn't surprise me if the good old network engineer had a copy of the old software lying around and installed it.

You can find out about the Norton Protected Recycle bin here http://www.symantec.com/avcenter/security/Content/2006.01.10.html

The idea is the same - when a user deletes files with certain extensions, the files get moved to another directory temporarily.